# How to terminate a process (not self) from inside a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa

If a Cocoa application needs to terminate another process (which it did not spawn) what APIs can be used to do this on 10.5 OS X ? Please note that process ID of the process to be terminated will not be known inside the Cocoa application. The process which needs to be terminated is also a Cocoa process.

Comment: If process ID is not known, is the process name known?

Answer (score 2):

Use NSWorkspace or Process Manager to find the process and obtain its PID, then use `kill` like usual.

Answer (score 2):

Iirc, NSWorkspace will only return processes owned by the user itself, however, there are of course many different ways to take care of this:

1.) [Document by Appple, QA1123](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2001/qa1123.html)

2.) [AGProcess from AGKit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/agkit/files/)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MachPortDump/Listings/MachPortDump_c.html

Answer (score 1):

```
NSRunningApplication* app = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:pid];
[app terminate]; // ask the target to terminate self
[app forceTerminate]; // the target will not save the data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve process Id before killing it. To kill a process, just send signal SIGABT, SIGTERM or SIGKILL to it.