# How to quit an application programatically in macintosh

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macos

I need to quit an application from another application. I know how to open another application from my application but I don't know how to quit it.

To Open other app:

```
 CFURLRef mtURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault,CFSTR("TestApplication:"), NULL);
    LSOpenCFURLRef(mtURL,nil);
```

Can any one please suggest on this?

Thank you,
Chandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you launching that app or is it already running?

If you are launching it yourself, instead of using your URL method, you could use a NSTask, that would give you more control on the exectution.

NSTask has a terminate message you can send.

See this page for some examples: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTask

---

Also see this SO question: [How to terminate a process (not self) from inside a Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622961/how-to-terminate-a-process-not-self-from-inside-a-cocoa-application)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it doesn't look like this is supported; there is only one function to close the application, and that function is deprecated. Perhaps you could send your application a message that your application could interpret and kill itself of its own volition?